# Does AudioRecorder read ever has a wait state?

Tags: android

Folks,

I am reading audio off the devices's microphone. Here is the pseudo code that is being run in a background thread:

```
while(true) {
   if (stopRecordingRequested()) {
       break;
   }
   int bytesRead = recorder.read(in, inSize);
   // do the processing
}
```

What I noticed is that method "read" returns data even if there is silence in the room.

I am thinking a tight loop such as the one above may simply peg the CPU even when the room is silent.

Is it possible to configure the audio recorder such that read() just waits until there is some noise?

Or, perhaps there is a different technique that doesn't peg the CPU.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure the audio recorder such that read() just waits until there is some noise?

No. The `AudioRecord` class isn't sophisticated enough to stop recording when the sound level drops below a certain point.

> Or, perhaps there is a different technique that doesn't peg the CPU.

Quite simply, don't use such a tight loop. Bearing in mind a loop as tight as you describe will execute every few ms or perhaps tens of ms it doesn't seem sensible to do it that way.

You have two basic choices...

1. When you set the audio format, sample rate and buffer size do so in such a way that you have, for example enough buffer for 5 seconds of recording. You can then use something like a `postDelayed` call on a `Handler` to read the buffer every 4 or 4.5 seconds (to avoid buffer overrun.
2. Use the `AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener` callback and set a position towards the end of the buffer (but not the very end - again to avoid overrun) and read the data every time the listener is called.